# Conditionally remove props from component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a list item that can be either expanded or clicked upon for a route.

What I would like to achieve, if the ListItem can be expanded, do not pass the NavLink component. So it will just be a ListItem.

```
<ListItem
        className="sidebar-item"
        onClick={onClick}
        button
        {...rest}
        component={NavLink}
        to={path}
        activeClassName="Mui-selected"
        exact
      >
```

I am not sure how i can exclude `component, to, activeClassName and exact` from passing into ListItem component.

Comment: how do you define the state for `expanded` and `clicked`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can destructure an empty object if the condition is false

```
if (someCondition === false) {
  conditionalProps = {};
} else {
  conditionalProps = {
    component: NavLink,
    to: {path},
    activeClassName: "Mui-selected",
    exact: true
  };
}

<ListItem
    className="sidebar-item"
    onClick={onClick}
    button
    {...rest}
    {...conditionalProps}
>
```

[image: Edit great-breeze-n6k47]

Answer (score 1):

Adding on @95faf8e76605e973 answer, you could cleanup the code a little bit by using inline condition.

```js
const conditionalProps = {
  component: NavLink,
  to: path,
  activeClassName: "Mui-selected",
  exact: true,
};

<ListItem
  className="sidebar-item"
  onClick={onClick}
  button
  {...rest}
  {...(someCondition && conditionalProps)}
>
```

Comment: looks good @bertdida (salamat) so it looks like this syntax works --> `var x = {...false}` or even `var x = {...123}`. interesting

Comment: Np tiny! Guess what? `{...null}` and `{...undefined}` works too. This is because in js, everything is an object.